# Confusing terminology?

Tags: sensor, automotive, terminology, code

I posted this question at motor vehicle stack exchange but I believe it's more suited for this.

I've noticed that many computer errors (diagnostic trouble codes PXXXX) in cars use confusing terminology to describe similar issues and I can't distinguish them, for instance here are three different sensor with various issues relating to them.

P0105 Manifold Abs.Pressure or Bar.Pressure **Voltage supply**

P0106 Manifold Abs.Pressure or Bar.Pressure **Range/Performance**

P0107 Manifold Abs.Pressure or Bar.Pressure **Low Input**

P0108 Manifold Abs.Pressure or Bar.Pressure **High Input**

P0109 Manifold Abs.Pressure or Bar.Pressure **Circuit Intermittent**

or

P0116 Engine Coolant Temp.Circ **Range/Performance**

P0117 Engine Coolant Temp.Circ **Low Input**

P0118 Engine Coolant Temp.Circ **High Input**

or

P0120 Throttle/Pedal Pos.Sensor A Circ **Malfunction**

P0121 Throttle/Pedal Pos.Sensor A Circ **Range/Performance**

P0122 Throttle/Pedal Pos.Sensor A Circ **Low Input**

P0123 Throttle/Pedal Pos.Sensor A Circ **High Input**

What exactly is meant by Malfunction, Range/Performance, Low Input, High Input and Circuit Intermittent? I've looked all over the place can't find a good explanation for these terms, are they generic terms used for all kinds of electric circuits or specific to cars?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not suitable/relevant for this site. Computer errors codes from proprietary equipment and explanations thereof are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific standards for the content of error messages in engineering. It is up to the individual manufacturer to designate the terms. Given that, some of them are relatively easy to interpret: Low Input means the sensor is generating a signal below its minimum expected value. High Input similarly means the sensor is generating a signal above its maximum expected value. Circuit Intermittent probably means that the sensor output is varying more than expected or disappearing entirely at times. The other terms are too general and one would need to refer to maintenance information for that product. Many consumer devices simply provide error codes and one must refer to the manual to find the meaning of these codes.